# How could the first programming language be created?

Tags: programming-languages, history

I know languages like Python are based in others, like C, to improve or modify some basic aspects of the language. So they parse the text you enter and act in reaction of that code.

But how was the first one written? **straight in binary?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and may be more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com if at all.

Comment: @deceze sorry i didnt know about that community. Thank you

Comment: BTW, consider: if magically all our software would  suddenly collectively disappear, even with all our hardware still intact... It would take years, if not decades again, before you'd be writing another line of something like Javascript. What most of us are using today is just layers built on layers built with tools built on layers etc. built on binary. It's literally decades of work below all of this today.

Comment: @deceze thats why technology improves faster and faster each year, no? Because layers improve their usability, and its easier to code the same thing in less lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first generation of codes used to program the functions of a computer was called machine language or machine code. Machine code is the language a computer really understands on a machine level, being a sequence of 0s and 1s that the computer's controls interprets as instructions electrically.

The second generation of code was called assembly language. Assembly language turns the sequences of 0s and 1s into human words like 'add'. Assembly language is always translated back into machine code by programs called assemblers.

The third generation of code, was called high level language or HLL, which has human sounding words and syntax (like words in a sentence). In order for the computer to understand any HLL, a compiler translates the high level language into either assembly language or machine code. All programming languages need to be eventually translated into machine code for a computer to use the instructions they contain.

Answer (score 3):

The first programming language was binary, which represents an on or off in the electrical circuits of the computer. But if you mean compilers of code, they were painstakingly written by pure machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was written straight in binary. It was the only way to tell the machine what you wanted it to do for you. In fact, in our days, programmers are still using these low-level languages to write more efficent code. If you want to code some kind of video editor application (resource-intensive) you will have to do it with these 1st generation of programming languages (like Assembler), because these have less abstraction than the ones that programmers are used to work with in order to get the application done in the shortest possible time, regardless how efficent it is (high-level languages).

Comment: So they are written from ground to be more effiient rather than using java or python, which would be less efficient?

Comment: Im talking about those you mentioned at the end , video and so on

Comment: That's right, imagine that when you work with JAVA you are reusing code that other programmers already built for general purposes. But if you want to create an app for a particular purpose It would be better to create your own code instead, because you would adjust every detail to your needs. Again, these kinds of software are not Android apps, could it be an OS or something like that.